# How to prevent Visual Studio 2015 reformatting on uncommenting a block

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If I comment out a block of code using the comment comment (Ctrl+E,C) and then uncomment (Ctrl+E,U) then the code is reformatted based on whatever options are set for things like braces in new lines, spacing around brackets, etc.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour and just leave the code as it was?

I don't recall seeing this behaviour prior to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: single ctrl+z undoes the formatting

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, the uncomment command puts two edit changes on the undo buffer - the actual uncommenting, and the reformatting. Hence the pressing Ctrl-Z will undo the reformatting and leave the uncommented code in place.

Answer (score 3):

OK I  just found the relevant setting:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> Advanced -> Pretty listing (reformatting) of code

Comment: I'm sure this was working yesterday, but it isn't working now. I suspect there's something contextual going on, i.e. there are some scenarios where this setting applies and some where another setting applies.